# Regarding possibility of developing Augmented reality android apps in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, support, unsupported-packages

I exhausted of installing or at least knowing which to install and how to install and to integrate them. Nothing is successful from 2-3 months.

I started reading many textbooks for developing Augmented reality apps. But faced difficulty with installation or availability of software required for developing apps.

Almost every Udemy course has this line

> A Windows or Mac Computer system

I did not see even a textbook or a course for developing Augmented reality Android apps in Ubuntu (preferably 18.04).

My question is that whether is it possible to develop augmented reality android apps in Ubuntu?

If yes, please give a reference material(either textbook/ blog/ lecture series, preferably free) that allows me to do in Ubuntu with details.

Comment: There are no tags related to reference-request, soft-question, textbook-recommendation etc., so please let me know if it is not an on-topic question

Answer (score 2):

You want to look up words like fuzzy logic and ARToolKit or FLARTools and get on mailing lists from places like sourceforge.com and github

What books have you read? Sadly Comp Sci books are outdated often by print time.

Look up Johnny Lee on youtube and see his wiimote head tracking hack. Since the IR camera is used there is some similarity to AR Symbol Packages. Do you have the 3DS Cards? Have you played the card game Eye Of Judgment. I got to work on localizsation of that but we weren't allowed to learn by looking at source code.

I am in the same boat I wanted to get a job at tineye.com or at least have them help me develop my Augmented Reality Fuzzy logic search algorithm for tiny.cc/OItoken and the binary scoring method of counting see this font for samples tiny.cc/OItokenfont

Comment: Augmented Reality for Android
Application Development and Augmented reality pro I had.

Comment: Can you please give links to the suggestions?